# How to run my few line of code asynchronously

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

i was trying to send mail asynchronously but i did not use asycn mail rather i use `Parallel.Invoke(() => {})` when i debug the code then i was it was not async because my next like after  `Parallel.Invoke` was block unit the mail was not send.

### here is my sample code

```
Parallel.Invoke(() =>
{
    var template = new MailTemplate()
    .WithBody("my sample body")
    .WithSubject("sample sub")
    .WithSender("test1@fakesite.com")
    .WithRecepient("test2@fakesite.com")
    .WithAttachment(filepath)
    .Send();                        
});

oLog.Save("no of job sone " + jbcount, false);
```

i like to confess my mail send routine is not async but i use `Parallel.Invoke`
to call those line asynchronously but when i debug then i saw `oLog.Save` was not invoke until the mail was sent.

so tell me how could run few line of code asynchronously as a result the code next after `Parallel.Invoke` should not be blocked.

Comment: Use `Task.Run()` instead of `Parallel.Invoke()`. (Offtopic: WithRecepient() is spelt wrong...)

Comment: @MatthewWatson thanks a lot it worked like a charm. :)

Answer (score 1):

Parallel.Invoke will run the various actions that you pass into it, in parallel, but will block until all are complete.

For example, you could do:

```
Parallel.Invoke(() => Console.WriteLine("Whaddup"), () => Console.WriteLine("Dawg"));

Console.WriteLine("Fo shizzle");
```

That would execute both of those commands at the same time, however it wouldn't write "Fo shizzle" until both of the other commands were finished, regardless of the order that they finished in.

As @MatthewWatson said above, use Task.Run instead, which will fire off your action in a separate thread and won't block until completion.

Parallel.Invoke is useful for doing a series of actions asynchronously (with respect to each other), but it's not an asynchronous method itself.

Comment: i complete my job done with Task.Run() instead. thanks for your code.